# Batch file to check if correct user logged in to continue setup else open .txt with warning inside to log into another user

Tags: batch-file

Hello i am trying to create a batch file to check if correct user logged in to continue setup else open .txt with warning inside to log into another user.

As far as i got is this(but i get both, my setup continues and a .txt files opens after it immediately):

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%f in ('wmic computersystem get username /value ^| find "="') do (
if /I "%%f" equ *\UVS ( goto setup
) Else ( 
goto ChangeUser
)
)
:ChangeUser
cls 
start notepad++ "D:\Install\TPCash_1.3-41-0038-HF01\TPCash_Server\Windows\Warning.txt"

:setup
```

I can't understand there is my mistake.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the `%username%` environmental variable direclty?  For your information, the `IF` command is a literal string comparison.  Meaning if you have quotes on one side of the comparison, they must be on the other side for the comparison to be true and the wildcard (asterisk) does nothing as well because it is a literal string comparison.

Comment: And when your loop is finished execution will continue at `:ChangeUser` unless you establish a countermeasure (like `goto :EOF`, for instance)…

Comment: Like your initial comment, I'd suggest, `If /I "%UserName%" == "UVS" GoTo setup`. As an alternative, if you wanted to use a [tag:for-loop], you could use `whoami.exe` instead of `WMIC.exe`. For example: `@For /F Delims^=^" %%G In ('"%__AppDir__%whoami.exe" /User /Fo CSV /NH') Do @If "%%~nxG" == "uvs" GoTo setup`.

Comment: Thank you very much, the whoami.exe solution was perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

This script is what i was looking for. Thank you very much, Compo :

Like your initial comment, I'd suggest

```
If /I "%UserName%" == "UVS" GoTo setup. As an alternative, if you wanted to use a for-loop, you could use whoami.exe instead of WMIC.exe. For example: @For /F Delims^=^" %%G In ('"%__AppDir__%whoami.exe" /User /Fo CSV /NH') Do @If "%%~nxG" == "uvs" GoTo setup.
```